# Are USB's Data+ and Data− needed when just charging?

Tags: usb

Are the data + and − wires in a USB cable needed if you just want to charge something?

Also what are the benefits and drawbacks of removing the data + and − wires?

Comment: I don't know the details, hence a comment: At least some telephones adapters put a non-USB standard circuit on the data-lines to indicate to the phone that it can draw more power than from a standard USB interface. So for that sort of devices it does matter if the data lines are attached or not.

Comment: I made an LED light on the USB power lines once without connecting the data wires to anything, so it's not necessary (but, as jippie shows, in some cases preferably). Take care with experimenting with the USB port by the way. When I was experimenting with this LED, I accidentally shorted the power, and the processor of the computer was fried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, something has to be done with the D+ and D- lines to guarantee you get more than 100 mA.  In practise, USB ports on wall-powered machines with large power supplies often don't bother actively controlling current.  On such machines, you can usually draw 500 mA.

For just supplying power when data communication is not wanted *and the host complies with the new USB high power standard*, you have to pull the data lines certain ways with particular resistances.  See the USB power spec for details of how to ask for high current, and how to know you actually got it.

Comment: If you want a normal USB host to supply more than 100mA, it's not enough to put some resistances there, you have to implement a proper USB device. The host reads the maximum amount of current needed by the device from the device descriptor, and the device may draw up to this amount only after it has been configured by the host (up until that, it may only draw 100mA). Of course, the majority of the USB hosts does not enforce this 100mA limit, instead, there's either no real limit at all (a short circuit will propagate to the PS of the host), or a fixed 500mA limit with a PTC, or an IC.

Comment: @Laszlo: I meant to say you use the resistors with a USB port specifically intended for charging, but I realize I forgot to say that.  This has now been fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Many USB powered devices use these lines to recognize charger.

> Most Android devices detect a charger looking for direct electrical
>   connection between D+ and D- pins (DC resistance 200 ohms maximum). If
>   they found it, the device draws the maximum current allowed and
>   battery charging is quite fast. If not, they assume they are connected
>   to a computer USB port and charging current is usually quite low,
>   taking an eternity to charge the battery or even no charging at all.

Source / more information: [link](http://ea4eoz.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-mini-iphone-chargers-with-android.html)

So, for some USB powered devices you can remove D+ and D- connection, but some may require it to enter "charging mode".

Comment: For example, the PS Vita will only show that it us charging when the data pins are shorted.

Answer (score 0):

it depends of your device. many cheap devices (powerbanks, small bluetooth headphones and speakers, other USB powered devices...) come with a cable that has only 2 wires inside. so do whatever you want with D+ and D-, there will be no effect. Those devices are usually drawing up to 500mA

For more power hungry devices or smartphones, there are different config possible : pins shorted together or not, with a resistor or not, with a potential or not... USB spec gives a standard, but the market is only following it halfway.